# i wanna get the max depth of a not-certain tree. the tree looks like below,how can i finish it

Tags: javascript, tree, depth

given a tree-structured data, get the max height of the tree. i wanna get the max depth of a not-certain tree. the tree looks like below:

```
{
      id: 1,
      label: 'label1',
      children: [{
        id: 3,
        label: 'label2',
        children: [{
          id: 4,
          label: 'label3'
        }, {
          id: 5,
          label: 'label4',
          disabled: true,
          children: [{
              id: 4,
              label: 'label3'
            }, {
              id: 5,
              label: 'label4',
              disabled: true
            }]
        }]
      }
```

i tried as below, but it did not work as expected.

```
const maxDepth = o => {

  if(!o || !o.children) return 0;

  let arr = []

  for(let i = 0; i< o.children.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = maxDepth(o.children[i])
  }

  let max = Math.max(...[arr]) + 1
  return max
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kosh :  i just posted my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe your data is formatted 100% correctly, so I took the liberty of doing so. That being said, this screams for a recursive algorithm.

```
{
  id: 1,
  label: 'label1',
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    label: 'label2',
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      label: 'label3'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      label: 'label4',
      disabled: true,
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        label: 'label3'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        label: 'label4',
        disabled: true
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

```js
test1 = {
  id: 1,
  label: "test1",
  children: []
}

test2 = {
  id: 2,
  label: "test1",
  children: [
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "test2",
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "test2",
    children: []
  }]
}

test3 = {
  id: 3,
  label: "test1",
  children: [
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "test2",
    children: [{
      children: [{
        children: [{}]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "test2",
    children: [{}]
  }]
}

your_data = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'label1',
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    label: 'label2',
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      label: 'label3'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      label: 'label4',
      disabled: true,
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        label: 'label3'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        label: 'label4',
        disabled: true
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

my_data = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'label1',
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    label: 'label2',
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      label: 'label3'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      label: 'label4',
      disabled: true,
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        label: 'label3'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        label: 'label4',
        disabled: true
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    label: 'madeup1',
    children: [{
      id: 7,
      label: 'madeup2',
      children: [{
        id: 8,
        label: 'madeup3',
        children: [{
          id: 9,
          label: 'madeup4'
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

function max_depth(exploringTheDepthsOf)
{
    largest = 0;
    if (exploringTheDepthsOf.hasOwnProperty('children'))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < exploringTheDepthsOf["children"].length; i++)
        {
            largest = Math.max(largest, max_depth(exploringTheDepthsOf["children"][i]));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return largest + 1;
}

console.log("returned value", max_depth(test1));
console.log("returned value", max_depth(test2));
console.log("returned value", max_depth(test3));
console.log("returned value", max_depth(your_data));
console.log("returned value", max_depth(my_data));
```

This is about as close as I could get. Geeks for geeks has a pretty good artical on it and javascript code to show you how to do it, but its for actual nodes, not for json like objects: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-n-ary-tree/